# How to deal with allBindings in ko3

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

In the ko 2 I used to add to the object returned by allBindingsAccessor() additional bindings while creating custom binding. It was convenient way to wrap complex bindings into a simple one.

I noticed that in ko 3 it is not work anymore - now there is the object allBindings with 'get' and 'has' methods. Unfortunately, it doesn't have 'set' method, so I can't add to my custom options binding optionsText and optionsValue anymore...

Any ideas how to get this work again?

Comment: simple illustration here 

http://jsfiddle.net/avbnB/1/    

(try with ko 2 and ko 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is better handled in Knockout 3.0 using the [preprocessing](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html) feature. Taking the example from your jsFiddle, here is how you'd implement that functionality in 3.0:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customList = {
    preprocess: function(value, name, addBinding) {
        addBinding('options', value);
        addBinding('optionsText', '"c"');
        addBinding('optionsValue', '"b"');
    }
};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/avbnB/3/